# How Golang implement stdin/stdout/stderr

Tags: go, stdin

I did a little program which was able to parse input from command line. It worked well by means of `std.in`. However, when I looked up the official document for further learning, I found there was too much stuff for me.

```
var (
   Stdin = NewFile(uintptr(syscall.Stdin), "/dev/stdin")
)
```

I read the document of `func NewFile`, `type uintpty`, `Package syscall` individually but could not figure out the whole. Also, I did not know the meaning of `/dev/stdin`, either.

I never learned another static programming language except for `go`. How could I realize the magic of `stdin`?

Comment: Down under Go is UNIX, usually. A good book for UNIX magic is https://www.amazon.com/Advanced-Programming-UNIX-Environment-3rd/dp/0321637739/ref=dp_ob_title_bk

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the `syscall` package, Stdin is just the number 0:

```
var (
        Stdin  = 0
        Stdout = 1
        Stderr = 2
)
```

This is simply because the posix standard is that stdin is attached to the first file descriptor, 0.

Since stdin is always present and open by default, `os.NewFile` can just turn this file descriptor into an `os.File`, and uses the standard Linux filepath "/dev/stdin" as an easily recognizable file name.

Comment: `/dev/stdin` is not POSIX.